# javascript convert datetime to local with specific format

Tags: javascript, datetime

I m having a date time text which i m converting to local dateTime using the javascript date time function toString();

```
 var txt = $(e).html();
     var date = new Date(txt);
     $(e).html (date.toString('yyyy-mm-dd'));
```

Now the toString method of javascript does not accept any parameters.

It always comes up with this format -

```
  Tue Aug 26 2014 03:30:34 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

I could not change the date format and had to go with a library date.js as [here](http://jsfiddle.net/brmr3623/7/)

Any help without any js frameworks.

Regards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: if you wanna use framework after all , i recommand using momentjs

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it yourself, something like:

```
var date = new Date(txt);
var dateStr = date.getDate()+'/'+date.getMonth()+'/'+date.getYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use `toLocaleFormat()` - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleFormat). But seems that it supports only in Firefox.

2) Write your own function which will do it. I provide example so you got main idea for it:

```
function dateFormat(format, date) {
    date = date || new Date();
    return format.replace('%m', date.getMonth());
}

var date = new Date();
console.log(dateFormat('Current month - %m', date));
```

3) Use libraries.